# Can't insert " character into Sqlite DB [Objective-C]

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm inserting some data on a sqlite db, It works fine but what I noticed is that I can't insert words that contains the character `"`, is it a common issue? should I change parse the text and edit every `"` character I find?

This is the code i'm using in order to insert data into my DB:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.customCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
        FolderProducts *item = _feedItems[indexPath.item];

        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &Carrello) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CarrelloMese (titolo, codice, prezzo, urlImg) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",item.nomeProdotto, item.codice, item.prezzo, item.urlImg];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(Carrello, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {

            } else {

            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(Carrello);
        }
```

Comment: Bind the variables to the prepare statement; that's what it's for.

Comment: @Droppy can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Prepared statements are designed so that you can prepare the statement once and bind different values into the placeholders while you execute the prepared statement multiple times.  This binding process will take care of escaping special characters, which is the issue in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ***bind*** your SQLite statements using the [sqlite3_bind_xxx()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) function. Basically, you remove all variables from your statement (in your case the %@) and replace them with '?'. SQLite then knows that where an ? is HAS to be a variable, and therefore doesn't get it mixed up with a command.

For example, say you wanted to bind the word "INSERT". Using ? SQLite won't read this as a command and then flag an error.

Read the docs (link above) for full information on how to use the bind function.

Here's what your code might look like with binding (UNTESTED):

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &Carrello) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CarrelloMese (titolo, codice, prezzo, urlImg) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(Carrello, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 0, item.nomeProdotto.UTF8String, item.nomeProdotto.length, SQLITE_STATIC) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred");
            }
            // Etc etc
            // SQLite bind works like this: sqlite_bind_text/int/e.t.c(sqlite3_stmt,index_of_variable, value); 
            // there are optionally parameters for text length and copy type SQLITE_STATIC and SQLITE_TRANSIENT.

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {

            } else {

            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(Carrello);
        }
```

Comment: Not the best coding example.  What's going on with `insertSQL`/`insert_stmt`?  Error checking and reporting is also lacking.  And you should not be encouraging the opening/closing of the database everytime a statement is run on it.

Comment: I copied and pasted his code and then added an sqlite_bind_xxx() function as an example. I agree the code could be improved (I personally wouldn't bother with NSStrings and just go straight with char*) but I felt that was outside the scope of the question.

Comment: just a typo, it's sqlite3_bind_text,    
Ty for the help!

Comment: @RASS excuse me one last question, shouldn't this bind function work for every kind of text format? Because now It works perfectly fine with the "" but for example I saw that a word with ò is saved wrong inside the db, do I need to change the .UTF8String to something else?
Thank you

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. I know that only the values 0 - 127 are reserved for ascii characters, characters like ø are displayed by text editors (I'm not sure how they're saved, probaly as attributed strings). It's quite possible that it's not possible to save non ASCII characters in an sqlite db. I suggest you get researching!